# Spark : no input file name

Tags: csv, apache-spark, filenames, hadoop-yarn

In an application, we read multiple csv files, we select some fields and then we write it to a single csv.

For each line that is written, we need to know which file it comes from. There is a built-in input_file_name() function that does not work for us:

```
df...
.withColumn("inputfilename_", input_file_name())
```

In the resulting file, there is always:

```
"inputfilename_":""
```

We use spark 2.1.0 with yarn. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: The function works for me. Could you please provide a minimal code sample so that we can reproduce your problem and help you better? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was reading a CSV, then joining another dataframe, then select the inputfilename() but that didn't work (in cluster mode, but that did in local!).

Now with

```
df.withColumn("inputfilename_", input_file_name())
  .join(...)
  .select($"inputfilename_")
```

ia looking for the inputfilename before the join, it works fine